# Why am I not able to install Ruby 1.9.2 on Mac OSX Lion?

Tags: ruby, rvm, osx-lion, ruby-1.9.2

I am trying to install Ruby 1.9.2 on a brand new MacBook Air with OSX Lion (10.7.2) and I keep getting an error message during the installation process. I'm new to Ruby and starting out with Ruby on Rails 3 Tutorial, so I downloaded RVM and then ran the command "$ rvm install 1.9.2." and this is what happened:

```
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/richardberger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290
ruby-1.9.2-p290 - #fetching 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 - #extracted to /Users/richardberger/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p290
Fetching yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/richardberger/.rvm/archives
Extracting yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/richardberger/.rvm/src
Configuring yaml in /Users/richardberger/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
ERROR: Error running ' ./configure --prefix="/Users/richardberger/.rvm/usr"  ',
please read /Users/richardberger/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p290/yaml/configure.log
Compiling yaml in /Users/richardberger/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
ERROR: Error running 'make ', please read
/Users/richardberger/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p290/yaml/make.log
Installing yaml to /Users/richardberger/.rvm/usr
ERROR: Error running 'make install', please read
/Users/richardberger/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p290/yaml/make.install.log
ruby-1.9.2-p290 - #configuring 
ERROR: Error running ' ./configure
--prefix=/Users/richardberger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290 --enable-shared
--disable-install-doc --with-libyaml-dir=/Users/richardberger/.rvm/usr ',
please read /Users/richardberger/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p290/configure.log
ERROR: There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

Any help or alternative solutions would be greatly appreciated. And since I am new to this, please let me know if I need to provide more info.

Thanks!

UPDATE: here is the info from the configure log:

```
[2011-10-13 11:26:35]  ./configure
--prefix=/Users/richardberger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290
--enable-shared --disable-install-doc
--with-libyaml-dir=/Users/richardberger/.rvm/usr
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-libyaml-dir
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin11.2.0
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin11.2.0
checking target system type... i386-apple-darwin11.2.0
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in
`/Users/richardberger/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p290':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details
```

Does this mean I need to download a C compiler (e.g. XCode?)

UPDATE (2): Problem solved by downloading Xcode!

Comment: In the second last line it says to check out the log. Have you ? Could you post it ?

Comment: What does the file `/Users/richardberger/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p290/configure.log` content?

Comment: Did you install XCode first? You can get it from the app store, but it installs an installer. You must then go run the installer it put in the applications folder.

Comment: as mentioned in the error output, you should look into the file "configure.log" .. can you post the relevant section? probably a missing dependency

Comment: thanks for the comments! i added the info from the configure.log above and i'm downloading xcode, so we'll see if that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH**

well, you don't have the Xtools development kit installed on your Mac!  e.g. there is no C compiler...

you should pop-in that OS X DVD or the Flash Drive which came with your computer, and **install Xtools**,
and after that try to install Ruby again..

Comment: Thanks so much Tilo (and everyone who commented). Downloading Xcode worked and I'm getting things all set up now.

Comment: RBergs, please [accept this answer if it helped you solve your problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). That will provide a clear indication that this question has been answered satisfactorily, provides future visitors an indicator about which answer worked (if any), and gives a little extra reputation to the one with the answer as an incentive to continue answering questions. Thanks!